# Twilio International SMS deliverability rate

Tags: twilio

We are sending SMS alerts globally and the contents are sensitive and deliverability is important for us.

Twilio offers many numbers for sending SMS from different countries. Is there any difference between Twilio numbers in terms of deliverability? are they perform the same? for example, if I choose a number from UK do I receive the same deliverability that I get from a number from Swiss?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Deliverability is different around the world, based on local carriers and restrictions. I recommend you check out the [SMS guidelines](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines) for the countries you are trying to send to to find out the best practices for ensuring delivery.